# android - Infinite HTML loop while calling json

Tags: android, json

I am new to android,
and trying to get the json value from backend but the response i am getting is not in json format it's in html format,

i am not getting any error but while i am debugging the program json value in this line `json = sb.toString();` is in html format and thus going in infinite loop.

```
 public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {


    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

i have restarted the server twice thinking it is a server problem, but it didn't help.

Thanks

Comment: Can put some logs and see if it is getting stuck at `json = sb.toString();` or in the `while` loop?

Comment: Seriously. What is your question? Is the HTML you get an error page? Where am I supposed to find the infinite loop you're talking of? Why did you implement an infinite loop? Or are you asking how _not_ to implement an infinite loop?

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar I am not getting an error but json response is in html

Comment: ok so the problem is that you are getting response as HTML whereas you want it to be in JSON. right? can you post the response? can you try the request from some rest tool?

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar  !DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
  <style>
    body { background-color: #fff; color: #333; }

    body, p, ol, ul, td {
....

It goes on for sometime

Comment: it looks like your server is throwing an un-handled Exception.. Contact the server team and show them the error.. Server should always return JSON object, if their is any error then the server should return error information in the JSON object... you also need to check the content type of the http response and only try to parse if the content type is JSON..

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar ok thanks for the help.I guess there is nothing wrong with the code